# How to use .p12 or .cer file to connect to SFTP?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, authentication, certificate, sftp

(I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter)

I have to connect to an external party's SFTP server. They gave me a `.p12` file, a `.cer` file, a password and an IP address. However, I can't seem to put those certificate files to good use, Google is currently not being my friend, and I'm not able to contact this external party for more information.

What I have tried so far:

- I have imported both the `.cer` and `.p12` files into my server's Trusted Root Certification Authorities, and verified that they are there.
- I have tried adding a `Workgroup` connection based on the IP address they gave me, but the IP address still cannot be resolved.
- I have tried connecting to the IP address directly with FileZilla, but I couldn't find an option to connect based on a certificate file.

Answer (score 2):

Certificates are more commonly used with TLS/SSL (FTPS), rather than SSH/SFTP.

Are you sure, you are supposed to connect with SFTP? Isn't it FTPS? These two are commonly mistaken.

---

Recent versions of OpenSSH support proprietary authentication method that indeed uses certificates. But I do not think, this method is supported by any other SSH/SFTP client. It's definitely not supported by FileZilla.

Comment: You're probably right -- it was simply my assumption that the method is SFTP.